# how to import intellij idea keymap to a text file (like csv)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to obtain a list of registered keybinding in the installed IntelliJ Idea. Existing way (`File -> Settings -> Keymap`) does not meet the use cases I interested to. For example,

- Find a function for certain keyboard shortcut
- Look for vacant keyboard shortcuts

The formatted list of keyboard shortcuts could be imported in spreadsheet software, R etc. What is the best way to obtain the mentioned list?

Comment: You can get the [complete keymap XML files here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps) and transform them to whatever format you want.

Comment: Be aware that some keymaps depend on others. Check the `parent` attribute on the root element for the "base class". Keybindings (`actions`) of a derived keymap will "override" those present in the base. This unfortunately created problems for me and other users, because some base keymaps are not available across all JB products and/or changed between versions.

Answer (score -1):

There ia a [KeyMap exporter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7066-keymap-exporter) plugin I cannot force to perform. Same project was placed to github:
[intellij-plugin-export-keymap](https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/intellij-plugin-export-keymap). So one can see through the code and try to find them own way.